# (js) moving div x pixels smoothly with jquery or similar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, move, smoothing

I have an image that when clicked should move a div up ~200px, I have it set through jquery to modify css without isssue but it doesn't look as 'clean' or smooth as i've seen on other websites.

Forgive me but i've been searching for a few hours and can't find the function/method to do this, I figured fadein/out would do this but i'm fairly sure it cannot.

Could anyone take a moment to point me in the right direction? Thank-you.

EDIT: After writing this I thought maybe I should quickly incrementally change the css via jquery to simulate a low-fps 'glide' .. hopefully there is an easier way

EDIT2: Currently use this, looking for a way to do it 'smoothly' if that even makes sense

```
$('#Table_Topbar').hide();
var pix = "px";
var fix = $('#Table_Middle1').css('top');
var fix2 = fix.replace('px','');
var fixsub = (fix2 - 200);  
var fixstring = fixsub.toString();
var fixconca = fixstring.concat(pix);
$('#Table_Middle1').css('top',fixconca);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this using only Javascript, you could also simply use an interval to update the css every xx number of milliseconds, for 60fps you'd use 16. (This is not the best way)

```
var i = parseInt($("#Table_Middle1").css("top"));
var animationLoop = setInterval(function() {  i += 10; $("#Table_Middle1").css("top",  i + "px"); }, 16);
```

A simpler way would be to use jQuery's animate api: http://api.jquery.com/animate/. (this is the most cross-browser friendly way)

```
$('#Table_Middle1").animate({top: "-=200px"}, 1000); // take 1 second to move up 200px
```

You could also use a [CSS3 transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_transitions) to accomplish the same thing, and reduce your JS to a simple class toggle (This is the most "modern" way)

```
jQuery: 
$('#Table_Middle1").addClass("class-to-trigger-animation");

css:
#Table_Middle1 { top: 500px; transition: top 1s ease; } 
#Table_Middle1.class-to-trigger-animation { top: 300px }
```

If you want more complex animations, you could consider a library like [Greensock](http://greensock.com).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of js (jQuery) and CSS here, eg.

CSS:

```
.switch {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; transition: top 1s}
.switch.active {top: 160px}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.switch').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/Lu7q2c1r/1/

You would need to adjust the parameters however, this is just a quick example.